# How to use Favicon Media without HTML Design on DXA Java 1.7?

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.7, multimedia

For our current implementation we are not using the HTML Design, and we've created a component to be included on our Header Include page, but as of now we always get the favicon as null 
Our Schema looks like this:
[image]

and the multimedia link allows only Favicon Schema:

[image]

Our entity is configured as:

```
@SemanticEntity(
    entityName = "customizeicon",
    vocabulary = SDL_CORE,
    prefix = "s",
    public_ = true
    )
    public class InternetFavicon extends AbstractEntityModel {
        @SemanticProperty("s:icon")
        private MediaItem icon;
    }
```

Is there a proper way to achieve this without the need to use HTML Design Configuration?

Comment: have you set the logging of your dxa webapp to debug ? Normally, if such issues occur, the modelbuilder should provide some logging, which should give you some indication of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the problem was a wrong mapped schema to the entity, after fixing that the problem is now gone.
This question can be closed.